# c++ - hackerrank project euler #1 terminated due to timeout

Tags: c++, timeout

There are many discussions on this topic. I went through them, but none helped.

The question seems fairly simple:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.
>
> Input Format  First line contains T that denotes the number of test
>   cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer, N.
>
> Output Format  For each test case, print an integer that denotes the
>   sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.
>
> Constraints  1≤T≤10^5  1≤N≤10^9

However, for two test cases, most probably the ones with a large input, my code results in terminated due to timeout.

Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    unsigned long long int n,t;
    unsigned long long int sum;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
        {
        sum=0;
        cin>>n;
        for(unsigned long long int i=3;i<n;i++){
            if(i%3==0 || i%5==0){
                sum+=i;
            }
        }
        cout<<sum<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why is it not working for large inputs even with unsigned long long int?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best or not, but you can have one loop for `3`, that will only iterate a *third* of your current implementation, and without `if` check as well. Think about that for a while.

Comment: You need to profile using large numbers to find out where most of the time is spent.

Comment: Resort to math. You are looking for the sum of all multipes of 3 plus the sum of all multiples of 5 minus the sum of all multiples of 15 smaller N, all of which can be calculated in constant time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest using two loops of addition and eliminating the expensive `%` operator.

Given that all the numbers that are divisible by 3 are also all the numbers that have the 3 added.  So rather testing a number for divisibility by 3 and summing them, only sum the numbers that are multiples of 3.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i + 3)
{
  sum += i;
}
```

If you also include the loop for 5, you would have all the values summed.

Also, subtract the values that are multiples of 15.

On the other hand, applying a little algebra and calculus, you could simplify the formula, then implement it.

### Some Analysis

The quantity of values divisible by 3 are less then `N/3`.  So for N = 13, there are 4 multiples of 3:  3, 6, 9, 12.  So the *limit* is N/3.

Breaking down algebraically, we see that the numbers for N = 13, are:

```
[1] (3 * 1) + (3 * 2) + (3 * 3) + (3 * 4)
```

Factoring out the common multiplying of 3 yields:

```
[2]  3 * ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4)
```

Looking at equation [2], this yields 3 * sum(1..N).

Using the [formula for summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation):

```
(x * (x + 1)) / 2
```

the equation can be simplified to:

```
[3] 3 * ( 4 * (4 + 1) ) / 2
```

Or replacing the total values by N/3 this formula comes out to:

```
[4] 3 * ((N/3) * ((N/3) + 1) ) / 2
```

The simplification of equation [4] is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I tried in python , you can check

```
def multiple(n): 
    return n*(n+1)/2
def sum(n): 
    return multiple(n/3)*3 + multiple(n/5)*5 - multiple(n/15)*15
for i in xrange(int(raw_input())):
    n = int(raw_input()) - 1
    print sum(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem timeout is probably set at a value that disallows brute force algorithms like yours. You can calculate the sum for any given value of N in constant time using the closed formula for summation of successive integers and De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter you`enter code here`r code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    long long int t, N, i=0, sum3=0, sum5=0, sum35=0;
    cin >> t;
    while(i<t){
        cin >> N;
        N=N-1;
        sum3 = 3 * ((N/3) * ((N/3) + 1) ) / 2;
        sum5 = 5 * ((N/5) * ((N/5) + 1) ) / 2;
        sum35 = 15 * ((N/15) * ((N/15) + 1) ) / 2;       
        cout << sum3 + sum5 - sum35 << endl;
        sum3=sum5=sum35=0;
        i++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```